# Show http header servlet not display anything

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers

This is one of my starting servlet that shows request(`client`) headers:

```
public class ShowHeaders extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title Request's HTTP Headers </title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<P> HTTP Headers Sent by your client: </p>");

    Enumeration enumeration = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
        String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
        out.println("<b>" + headerName + " </b> ");
        out.println(headerValue + "<br>");
    }
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

my `web.xml` file:

```
...
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ShowHeaders</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jspbook.ShowHeaders</servlet-class>

 </servlet>


 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShowHeaders</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShowHeaders</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
...
```

But the problem is that when i deploy it correctly and try `http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspbook/ShowHeaders` , just a blank page displays!

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Nothing appears wrong with your code. Have you looked at the container logs?

Comment: @bmargulies No, Where is container log, and what is it's name?

Comment: Since you haven't told us what container you are using, I can't answer that question. Tomcat? Jetty? Something Else?

Comment: Try adding an `out.flush()` at the bottom, maybe?

Comment: @bdkosher After the `/html/ or before the last brace?

Comment: Right after the `out.println("</html>");` line

Comment: @bdkosher I did it, but make no sense!

Comment: The code looks fine. It is most likely a deployment issue. Did you check for errors in Tomcat's log (catalina.out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out.println("<title> Request's HTTP Headers </title>");
```

just close your `title tag`

[image]

Comment: Yes, and so confused me!

Comment: That's happens with all of us 

Comment: :) , I feel nice with you, Are you studied computer science?

Comment: Yes, its more confusing then above problem "I feel nice with you "

Comment: :) , That's means equivalent that "I feel friendly with you" !